# if a variable equals a letter or word

Tags: php, mysql

Think it is quite obvious what i am trying to do. If gender variable is M then display the male image. I have tried a few things such as removing an =, but i am not having any success.

Have i got this completely wrong?

```
if ($gender == M){
<img src='images/male.png' width='45px' height'45px'>
}else{
($gender == F){
 <img src='images/female.png' width='45px' height'45px'>
}else{
($gender == HIDE){
<img src='images/uni.png' width='45px' height'45px'>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless those are constants, you need to encapsule the strings in quotes:

```
if($gender == 'M') {
?>
<img src="images/male.png" width="45" height="45" />
<?php
} else {
```

Also, pay attention (your code gives syntax errors) on how you mingle html and php. And you should use CSS for styling, not inline attributes (which are deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have set php constant definitions for `M`, `F`, and `HIDE`, then you need to make those into strings.

constants: http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Also remember, there aren't enumeratios in php.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try a switch statement like:

```
switch(strtoupper($gender))
{
    case 'M': $gender_img = 'male'; break;
    case 'F': $gender_img = 'female'; break;
    case 'HIDE': $gender_img = 'uni'; break;
    default: $gender_img = 'uni'; break;
}

echo '<img src="images/'.$gender_img.'.png" width="45px" height="45px">';
```

Answer (score 0):

if ($gender === 'M'){

```
// or to make sure $gender is uppercase:
if (strtoupper($gender) === 'M'){
...
}
elseif { ...
```

And, your first "else" should be an elseif

Answer (score 0):

I would do it inline (like a boss)

```
<img src="imgs/<?=($gender=="m"?"male.jpg":($gender=="f"?"female.jpg":"uni.jpg"))?>" />
```